# Navigate/pre-populate view for multiple defects via hyperlink to HP ALM/Quality Center

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I know I can link to an individual defect via a hyperlink such as the one below:

```
td://[project].[domain].[server]:[port]/qcbin/Defects?Action=FindDefect&DefectID=188416
```

Is there a way to go to multiple defects by calling a different action or passing multiple IDs?

I've tried common patterns such as:

```
td://[project].[domain].[server]:[port]/qcbin/Defects?Action=FindDefect&DefectID=188416&DefectID=188550
td://[project].[domain].[server]:[port]/qcbin/Defects?Action=FindDefect&DefectID=188416+188550
td://[project].[domain].[server]:[port]/qcbin/Defects?Action=FindDefect&DefectID=188416%2018550
```

REST API is not an option as I don't want to replace the ALM UI; I want to redirect users to it so they can manage defects and look up data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "td://" protocol doesn't support manipulating multiple entities from a single url, at least not for now.

Though it has another param "ALL_ENTITY_IDS" allowing multiple IDs but that mainly is used for filters.